# App integration with Vuforia SDK for iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, vuforia

I'm new in Vuforia SDK for iPhone. I want to do an application similar to the Books example but i don`t know how to change the application in order to do the following

1. Scan a logo of a company(i have already created the image database
   and inserted the access and secret key)
2. Get the metadata I included in the logo image(just a string with name, description and an url to the companies web page)
3. Show the information previously acquired in a new simple screen
4. include a back button so i can scan again.

This is all based in the Books example.

Comment: So you basically want us to write your app? Maybe you should elaborate more on what exactly is the problem and what doesn't work, or what can't you figure out. I suggest learning the basics of Objective-C/iOS first, if you don't know any of these steps above (especially n. 3).

Comment: i know IOS/Objective C just wanted to know if there was a way to use the samples or i have to do an app and integrate only the SDK thats my real question (which classes do i need to use in order to scan the logo and incorporate the metadata inside my images in the app)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use cloud recognition to retrieve the meta data and use NSNotification to pass data from the cloud reco class to your objective c or swift class.